# -NoNewLine Not working as expected in Powershell

Tags: powershell, newline, separator

I am using powershell to concatenate a key but the Writehost is giving me a carriage delimiter and 3 lines instead of a single line when using      -NoNewLine.

I have tried -NoNewLine along with various other code sets such as

```
write-host -replace "[`r`n](-join(
```

Bearer 
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik5VTTBSRFE1UVROQk9FRTJNREJEUWtGR1JEazFNRGN4TlRReU9FUXpOalZFT0RZeVJEQXpSZyJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2lkZW50aXR5LmF1dGgwLWRldi5zcy5hd3MuYmNpZGFoby5jb20vIiwic3ViIjoidHFYQjEw
ejVUT0ZvZ05rNDAzQmZYZkhrTkJxSVJ0UENAY2xpZW50cyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vaWRlbnRpdHkuYXV0aDAtZGV2LnNzLmF3cy5iY2lkYWhvLmNvbS9hcGkvdjIvIiwiaWF0IjoxNTUzNTI2MDk0LCJleHAiOjE1NTM2MTI0OTQsImF6cCI6InRxWEIxMHo1VE9Gb2dOazQwM0JmWGZIa05C
cUlSdFBDIiwic2NvcGUiOiJyZWFkOmNsaWVudF9ncmFudHMgY3JlYXRlOmNsaWVudF9ncmFudHMgZGVsZXRlOmNsaWVudF9ncmFudHMgdXBkYXRlOmNsaWVudF9ncmFudHMgcmVhZDp1c2VycyB1cGRhdGU6dXNlcnMgZGVsZXRlOnVzZXJzIGNyZWF0ZTp1c2VycyByZWFkOnVzZXJzX2FwcF9t
PeIoyImIORI59k0Ee_Ay4jlSpiPT_FEdlln_ZWfcEDCPQ

I also have been scouring Stack overflow and everyone says having the no new line should be the answer

```
$assoc1 ="Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik5VTTBSRFE1UVROQk9FRTJNREJEUWtGR1JEazFNRGN4TlRReU9FUXpOalZFT0RZeVJEQXpSZyJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2lkZW50aXR5LmF1dGgwLWRldi5zcy5hd3MuYmNpZGFoby5jb20vIiwic3ViIjoidHFYQjEw" 
$assoc2 ="ejVUT0ZvZ05rNDAzQmZYZkhrTkJxSVJ0UENAY2xpZW50cyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vaWRlbnRpdHkuYXV0aDAtZGV2LnNzLmF3cy5iY2lkYWhvLmNvbS9hcGkvdjIvIiwiaWF0IjoxNTUzNTI2MDk0LCJleHAiOjE1NTM2MTI0OTQsImF6cCI6InRxWEIxMHo1VE9Gb2dOazQwM0JmWGZIa05C" 
$assoc3 ="cUlSdFBDIiwic2NvcGUiOiJyZWFkOmNsaWVudF9ncmFudHMgY3JlYXRlOmNsaWVudF9ncmFudHMgZGVsZXRlOmNsaWVudF9ncmFudHMgdXBkYXRlOmNsaWVudF9ncmFudHMgcmVhZDp1c2VycyB1cGRhdGU6dXNlcnMgZGVsZXRlOnVzZXJzIGNyZWF0ZTp1c2VycyByZWFkOnVzZXJzX2FwcF9t"


$apikey = ($assoc1,$assoc2,$assoc3)


write-host $apikey  -NoNewLine
```

I would expect this to run and the result to be one line

```
"Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik5VTTBSRFE1UVROQk9FRTJNREJEUWtGR1JEazFNRGN4TlRReU9FUXpOalZFT0RZeVJEQXpSZyJ9.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"
```

instead the result set gives me 3 lines of codes instead of 1. Is this a limitation on powershell?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pP5jk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just join them, this way...

```
$assoc1,$assoc2,$assoc3 -join ''
```

Though this will show as 3 lines on screen, because of screen formatting, it is not.

```
($assoc1 ="Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik5VTTBSRFE1UVROQk9FRTJNREJEUWtGR1JEazFNRGN4TlRReU9FUXpOalZFT0RZeVJEQXpSZyJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2lkZW50aXR5LmF1dGgwLWRldi5zcy5hd3MuYmNpZGFoby5jb20vIiwic3ViIjoidHFYQjEw" ).Length
($assoc2 ="ejVUT0ZvZ05rNDAzQmZYZkhrTkJxSVJ0UENAY2xpZW50cyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vaWRlbnRpdHkuYXV0aDAtZGV2LnNzLmF3cy5iY2lkYWhvLmNvbS9hcGkvdjIvIiwiaWF0IjoxNTUzNTI2MDk0LCJleHAiOjE1NTM2MTI0OTQsImF6cCI6InRxWEIxMHo1VE9Gb2dOazQwM0JmWGZIa05C" ).Length
($assoc3 ="cUlSdFBDIiwic2NvcGUiOiJyZWFkOmNsaWVudF9ncmFudHMgY3JlYXRlOmNsaWVudF9ncmFudHMgZGVsZXRlOmNsaWVudF9ncmFudHMgdXBkYXRlOmNsaWVudF9ncmFudHMgcmVhZDp1c2VycyB1cGRhdGU6dXNlcnMgZGVsZXRlOnVzZXJzIGNyZWF0ZTp1c2VycyByZWFkOnVzZXJzX2FwcF9t").Length

($apikey = $assoc1,$assoc2,$assoc3 -join '').Length

# Results 
220
220
220
660

$apikey.Count
1

$apikey | clip
```

If you paste this into notepad, without 'Word Wrap' on, you'll see it's one line.

```
Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik5VTTBSRFE1UVROQk9FRTJNREJEUWtGR1JEazFNRGN4TlRReU9FUXpOalZFT0RZeVJEQXpSZyJ9.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
```

Comment: Thank you it was the screen formatting that when I tried to copy over to test in the API the token was not authenticating. Because it cant have carriage breaks. Thank you so much! I have about 10 more keys to concat and see if it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you want your 3 **strings to be joined *without separators***, i.e., to be directly concatenated, **use the unary form of the `-join` operator**:

```
$apikey = -join $assoc1, $assoc2, $assoc3
```

If you want to **output that single string *without a trailing newline***:

- To *print to the console only*, you can use `Write-Host -NoNewline $apikey`

  - Note that **as an *artifact of display in the console* your single-line string may still display across multiple lines**, depending on the window / buffer width of your console window.
- To save to a file, use `Set-Content -NoNewline` or `Out-File -NoNewline` (PSv5+).